# How import between multi-site Django projects

Tags: django

How can I import models and views from Django Site1 to Site2 using the Sites Framework?

```
Django Sites Framework scenario

top

  ----site1

  ----site2

  ----media


#File on Site 2: views.py

from site1.article.models import Model1, Model2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's sites framework is about sharing the same code on different sites (in the end different Django instances with one codebase and one database).

Your directory structure suggests that you are doing it wrong: you should *not* have multiple site apps, putting your stuff in site1 and importing it into other site apps.

Instead you should code your Django Apps with the help of the sites framework:

- add a site reference to your models where it makes sense
- setup multiple Django instances each with its own `SITE_ID` in `settings.py`
- your model objects can then be filtered by `Site.objects.get_current()`

You can do this in elaborate ways (Model inheritance, custom Managers for automatic filtering), but this is the basic description.